# Access active spline from Bezier Curve

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I'm just starting to get familiar with bpy.types and application modules, but I didn't find an answer to this:

Concerning A Bezier Curve with multiple splines, is there a python way in EDIT mode to know on which spline I am working on (activated in the viewport) except iterating every single bezier_point inside ?

Thanks in advance,
jimflim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access this from the spline collections.

```
obj = bpy.context.object
curve = obj.data
spline = curve.splines.active
```

http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/bpy.types.CurveSplines.html#bpy.types.CurveSplines.active